# Play M4V in background IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uikit, mpmovieplayercontroller, avfoundation

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to play an m4v file in the background with buttons that overlay ontop of the video?  The video is basically an animation (no sound) but I need to be able to add additional navigation on top of the animation to bring in other calls in the app.

Is that possible to do?  If so what is the call that would be required?  I've tried hunting around but can't find an answer yet

Answer (score 0):

You can use MPMoviePlayerController, set control style to none, and put your own buttons on top of it.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html